# Finding the nth triangular number

Tags: python, programming-challenge

```
def triangularNumber(n):
    if(n == 1):
        return 1
    else:
        return triangularNumbers(n-1)+n
```

works great to find the nth triangular number up to 996...
I get some error in the recursion after 996. But can tell what it is because it just keeps running through the loop. Anyone see the error?

Comment: You are probably getting a [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) (the error, not the website `;)`)

Answer (score 6):

Using recursion is generally advised against, as it takes longer that iterating, and can run into what you ran into, a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. Note you [can change the maximum recursion depth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323013/4237459), but it is generally advised against, and can lead to stack or memory overflows. In this case, you should iterate.

```
def triangular_number(n):
    i = n
    while True:
        if i == 1:
            return n
        i -= 1
        n += i
```

(This keeps running in *the same* function call, reducing the addition factor by one each time.)

Or better yet, use a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) (or xrange for Python 2):

```
def triangular_number(n):
    for i in range(n):  # range(3) is a generator for [0, 1, 2]
        n += i
    return n
```

Or better yet, use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
def triangular_number(n):
    return sum(range(n + 1))
```

Or, even better, use the [formula for triangle numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

```
def triangular_number(n):
    return n * (n + 1) // 2  # Convert to int for Python 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advice writing a more general function and then maybe defining an helper, like:

```
def polygonal(n, sides):
    return (n**2*(sides-2) - n*(sides-4)) // 2

def triangular(n):
    return polygonal(n, 3)
```

This may take a little bit more code, but will allow easier use of other n-gonals numbers.

Please note that you may do without `triangular` and call:

```
polygonal(n, sides=3)
```

Comment: Also, note you can do `triangular = functools.partial(polygonal, sides=3)`.